# A simple Java average calculator

Tags: java, loops

I'm a new Java student(self studying at home), and I made this average calculator which works perfect, but I wanted to add a condition that prevents the user from typing in a number bigger then 100, because grades usually end at 100, I'm struggling a bit on what is the right way of doing so.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class books{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total = 0;
        int grade = 0;
        int average;
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter all your grades:");
        while(counter < 12){
            grade = userInput.nextInt();
            total = total + grade;
            counter++;
            if(grade > 100){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid grade");

            }
        }
        average = total/12;
        System.out.println("You average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before using the entered `grade` value, you should validate it and if it's not valid, to continue with the loop:

```
while(counter < 12){
    grade = userInput.nextInt();
    if (grade > 100) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid grade");
    } else {
        total = total + grade;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Also, when calculating the *average* of multiple values, it's not that good idea to do integer division, because you can get wrong results. Better do:

```
double average = 0d;
...
average = total / 12.0;
```

Comment: Thanks! thats what I was looking for, the "continue" keyword, I simply wanted it to skip the wrong entered value and not to count it as the average...

Comment: Note that since the computation is in the `else` block, you don't really need the `continue` command.

Comment: btw, do you have any book or videos series for learning Java to recommend me? for now I'm learning by watching "thenewboston" youtube series, which is good, but I would like to learn from another "angle" ;)

Comment: It's full of free books and videos on the Internet. Just Google for some and  you'll find tones.

Comment: I added the || operator, so the value wont be under 0 aswell :)

Comment: Kocko, I agree, but for grades, you get a whole number, so it doesn't really neccesary :D

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class books{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total = 0;
        int grade = 0;
        int average;
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter all your grades:");
        while(counter < 12){
            grade = userInput.nextInt();
            if(grade > 100 || grade < 0){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid grade again!");
            }else{
                total = total + grade;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        average = total/12;
        System.out.println("You average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Credit goes to Kocko ;)